# Zabbix API get.event api pull issues

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

Looking for some insight on this one.

I have currently written the below code where I am connecting to a local zabbix monitoring software I have set up. I am able to connect and pull data from all other API pulls such as host.get and problem.get. However I only have temporary luck with the event.get API pull. Sometimes it will work and I am able to download and output the result into a CSV, but more often than not I get this error.

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

full traceback log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lachlan.ballard\Corp Projects\MapDisplayAllScripts\eventget.py", line 9, in <module>
    geteventlist = r.json()['result']
  File "C:\Users\lachlan.ballard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lachlan.ballard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\lachlan.ballard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\lachlan.ballard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Please see my full code below and see if I am missing why it would:

A. Be intermittently working
or
B. Why it errors in the first place

(I am aware that the error itself gives some insight as to the error, however the data it is pulling has full data from first point to last, and wouldnt make sense as to why it would only work *sometimes*

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://localzabbixhost'
payload = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "event.get", "params": {"output": "extend", "selectAcknowledges": "extend", "selectTags": "extend", "selectSuppressionData": "extend", "selectHosts": ["hostid", "host", "name"], "recent": "true", "sortorder": "DESC"}, "auth": "specialpasskey", "id": 1 }'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json-rpc'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, )

geteventlist = r.json()['result']

df = pd.DataFrame(geteventlist)
df = pd.json_normalize(geteventlist, record_path='hosts', meta=['eventid'], errors='ignore') 
df.to_csv('expandedhosts.csv') #converting the dataframe into a csv
```

Thanks in advance all. Let me know if you need anything further

**EDIT** If I catch the variable 'r' before being passed into the offending line, I am receiving the following error:

`<Response [500]>`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up not being a zabbix error but instead a DB error where PHP was maxxing out the amount of data it can pull and therefore rejecting everything